# at the end of a hypotenuse line image bounces back and forth from 2 points close to the end point

Tags: java, android

I am trying to learn to make game for the Android. I am trying to make an image move along a hypotenuse line.

I got the math and code down (I think, got it from some place off google) but what happens is that after it travels down the line (which it looks like it does fine) when the image comes to the end of the line it "bounces" between 2 points right next to the destination point. like it can't get to the end of the line so it just goes to the 2 closest points it can get to and jumps back and forth between them.

The question:
How would I get it to not jump from the 2 points and stick to the point at the end of the Hypotenuse line?

Here is my code:

```
// to find the distance between the 2 points 
distX = endX - imaX;
distY = endY - imaY;
// find the hypotenuse
hyp = Math.sqrt(distX*distX + distY*distY);
// don't know what this is for 
len = 160/hyp;
distX *= len;
distY *= len;

// and to move the image. The points have to be an int.
imaX += (int) (distX * 0.05); 
imaY += (int) (distY * 0.05);
```

Thank you:)
Edit: added the question and fixed the error I made in here.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

If you googled this code, you should keep googling. It's a confusing piece of overkill if all you want to do is travel a line.

Consider the case when you are exactly one pixel away in both dimensions:

```
distX = 1
distY = 1
hyp = sqrt(2) ~1.414
len = 160/hyp ~ 113.15

imaX += (113.15 * 0.05) ~ 5
imaY += (113.15 * 0.05) ~ 5
```

So, if you're one pixel away in both the X/Y dimensions, it'll try to move 5 pixels in each direction each time. Not good

You should also try to achieve framerate independence, which is something this code can't handle. There are literally [tons of articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=framerate%20independent%20movement&aq=f&oq=framerate%20independent%20movement&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l2j62l2.5872&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) about this on the web.

**Edit:** oh, and it should be:

```
hyp = Math.sqrt(distX*distX + distY*distY);
```

You confused a multiply with an add.

Comment: Sorry I've only been studding Java and android development for a week :) How would I go about the framerate independence thing? any where you can point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you've only been at it for a week, you may need some basics before you jump all the way in. I'd check out [JavaGaming.org](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=tvlcuiovvaagcpq4841jve4810&action=resources) for some good tutorials about game concepts in Java.